# Spring Boot with Elastic Search causing java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch

I'm new to Elastic search. Started building a Spring boot application with Elastic search.

Using the latest ES version `"elasticsearch-7.7.1"` and for integration, I'm using below maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added below configuration to my spring boot app:

```
@Configuration
public class ESConfig {

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  public RestHighLevelClient client() {
    RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost")));
    return restHighLevelClient;
  }

}
```

Added below properties to application.yaml

```
elasticsearch:
  host: localhost
```

Getting below Exception on Application startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.<clinit>(RestHighLevelClient.java:1902)
    at com.sbs.communicationcontrol.search.config.ESConfig.client(ESConfig.java:14)
```

**Can anyone please help why this exception occurred?**

Comment: Check your elastic version. Must be the same version of a driver. Are be same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some R&D, fixed the issue by adding below two dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me using spring-boot 2.1.5-RELEASE and elastic search 7.9.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem when I was upgrading to `org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.8.1` from `6.8.5`. The reason behind the problem is updating `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` alone to the latest version conflicts with some of its dependent elastic search dependencies which were brought into classpath as transitive dependencies by spring-boot. When I check with the dependency tree, I found that the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.3.1.RELEASE` dependency brings `org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.6.2`, `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.6.2` and the 7.6.2 conflicts with `7.8.1`.

An Excerpt code snippet from the `RestHighLevelClient` citing `IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS` Java Docs.

```
public class RestHighLevelClient implements Closeable {
    ....
    ....
    /**
     * Ignores deprecation warnings. This is appropriate because it is only
     * used to parse responses from Elasticsearch. Any deprecation warnings
     * emitted there just mean that you are talking to an old version of
     * Elasticsearch. There isn't anything you can do about the deprecation.
     */
    private static final DeprecationHandler DEPRECATION_HANDLER = DeprecationHandler.IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS;
   .....
   .....
}
```

The error itself indicates us to update all related elasticsearch libraries, though I couldn't find any out-of-box `elastic search BOM` to resolve this version conflicts, I have done the below workaround.

```
dependencies{

    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.8.1'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.8.1'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.8.1'

}

//Since version 7.6.2 is selected by rule, substituting the version 7.8.1 as below

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client') with module('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.8.1')
            substitute module('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client') with module('org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.8.1')
            substitute module('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch') with module('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.8.1')
            
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly initializing your elasticsearch client, can you try with below code:

Please note that I am using the version which accepts the host, port and `http` scheme and it works fine for me and is the [standard for creating the client.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html)

```
@Configuration
@Primary
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    /**
     * Creates a Elasticsearch client from config
     *
     * @return Elasticsearch client
     */
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9500, "http")));
        return client;
    }
}
```

And use below config

```
elasticsearch.host=localhost
elasticsearch.port=9500
```

Comment: did not fix the issue, still facing same issue!

Comment: @DevChauhan can you use the 7.6.0 version of rest client, also can you upload your code to github so that I can have a look and repro

Answer (score 0):

You can set the version for all of the Spring-boot:

```
ext {
    set('elasticsearch.version', '6.2.0')
}
```

to avoid overriding it in multiple places.